# OnMouseDown should not work over NGUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I have gameobjects where OnMouseDown event attached and its event working fine but the problem is the event is also working when NGUI UITexture is open. I want to prevent OnMouseDown when mouse over the UITexture. I have used

```
UICamera.hoveredObject
```

but it still detecting onMouseDown event from UITexture.

Comment: have you tried using `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`

Comment: Yes, but it is not working as I am using NGUI.